# (Java) Determine if a specific number appears twice in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The problem is that I need some way to find out if an array list contains a duplicate number when asked for a specific number.

The base code that I have been given is:

```
public static boolean moreThanOnce(ArrayList<Integer> list, int number) {
    // write your code here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(3);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(2);

    System.out.println("Type a number: ");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    if (moreThanOnce(list, number)) {
        System.out.println(number + " appears more than once.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(number + " does not appear more than once.");
    }
}
```

I honesty need help on deciding which direction to go. Since it needs to work if the object appears twice or more, I can't simply flip the Boolean when it detects that a specific number appears since that if the number appears 3 times then it will fail.

I appreciate some advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Have a counter for the times `number` appears in `list`. Increase the counter every iteration you come across `number`. Return based on if that counter is greater than 1.

Comment: Ok will try it thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Collections.frequency(list, object)` to find the count of occurrence  object in ArrayList

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   list.add(3);
   list.add(2);
   list.add(7);
   list.add(2);

 System.out.println("Type a number: ");
 int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
 if (Collections.frequency(list, number)>1 ) {
      System.out.println(number + " appears more than once.");
 } else {
  System.out.println(number + " does not appear more than once.");
   }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the idea of this exercise is to use a library function.

Comment: can you please be more specific @Henry, but by having predefine methods doing task for us, really do we need to write that logic again?

Comment: @Henry Who said it was an assignment/exercise & not a problem he's trying to overcome in his own independent project? I don't believe SO was intended for exercises.. Shouldn't you be closing this as a duplicate? There's no purpose in trying to "bust" this answer which works perfectly fine, unless you're trying to change what SO aims for.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - There are strong clues in the source code that the OP provided that he is doing a "learning exercise" of some kind.   And another clue is that he said: *"The base code that i have been given is:"*.  Also, you said:   *"I don't believe SO was intended for exercises."* - We know that ... but does the OP?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) I think it’s a good answer, and if for no other reason you should leave it here for other readers coming along.

Comment: @StephenC It was a rhetorical question, sorry. My point was these types of questions rarely bring value to the site. The only problem with this answer is that it doesn't help the OP get an A on their assignment, albeit being extremely useful for others (hence the upvotes). Encouraging answers which solve duplicate problems, ones the OP should talk to their professor about, only shows others it's okay to post & support content like this. OleVV, although it may fit in terms of homework, it doesn't fit in terms of duplicate, like most questions similar to this.

Comment: but if given object is not present list it will return `0` right @OleV.V.

Comment: can someone explain me, why down votes even though answer is correct?

Comment: @Deadpool `frequency > 1` will always ensure `frequency != 0` is true (it *can't* be `0` if it's greather than `1`). It was fine before; the `&& Collections.frequency(list, number) != 0` isn't needed.

Comment: @Deadpool 0 is not greater than 1, so if the object is not present, the first part of the condition will correctly determine that it doesn’t come twice, and the second half will never be evaluated anyway. Try it out. If you think your version is more readable, just leave it as it is.

Comment: Correct answers to (very) poor questions often attract downvotes (I upvoted).